# Using placeholder for react-native-picker

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, datepicker

I am new to react-native. please help me to solve this issue. I have been trying to display react-native-picker on the homepage (without any user action) by default. My code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-picker';
let data = [];
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
       data.push(i);
 }
```

and added datepicker in component class (render function) like this

```
<DatePicker pickerData={data} selectedValue= {59}    />
```

I got error as

```
 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Please help me to solve this. I tried with

```
DatePicker.init({
    pickerData: data,
    selectedValue: [59],
    onPickerConfirm: data => {
        console.log(data);
    },
    onPickerCancel: data => {
        console.log(data);
    },
    onPickerSelect: data => {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
DatePicker.show();
```

Those were fine. But i wanted to display in view on the home page without any actions.

Comment: Did you try `import Picker from 'react-native-picker';` instead of `DatePicker`

Comment: you can choose from this following example for what exactly you need : https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker/blob/master/example/PickerTest/index.js

Comment: @astiefel  Yes tried. but not working

Comment: @GaneshCauda Hi, thanks for the example, but that example will open the datepicker on some events (like onpress). i wanted to open it without any event on the home page.

Comment: You can call the init/show on `componentDidMount` and that would automatically open when the page mounts

Comment: @astiefel yes it helped me. Thank you.